# Use arraydeque to implement MonitonicQueue

Tags: java, linked-list, deque, arraydeque

I'm using the `Deque` to implement a monotonic queue. I know that `Deque` can be created by both `ArrayDeque` and `LinkedList`. Here is the Monotonic class I constructed:

```
public static class MonotonicQueue {
    Deque<Integer> monotonicQueue;

    public MonotonicQueue() {
        monotonicQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    }

    void push(int n) {
        while (!monotonicQueue.isEmpty() && monotonicQueue.getLast() < n) {
            monotonicQueue.removeLast();
        }
        monotonicQueue.addLast(n);
    }

    int max() {
        return monotonicQueue.getFirst();
    }

    void pop(int n) {
        if (!monotonicQueue.isEmpty() && n == monotonicQueue.getFirst()) {
            monotonicQueue.removeFirst();
        }
        monotonicQueue.addLast(n);
    }
}
```

However, the issue appears in the `void push(int n)` method, which means delete all elements which are `< n`, and then add `n` into the queue of the tail. I initialized a variable `window` in a method and then tried to push an element to update this monotonic queue.

```
MonotonicQueue window = new MonotonicQueue();
window.push(3);
```

But it even fails to insert the first element. The weird thing is when I use the second way in the constructor, say `LinkedList<>` instead of `ArrayDeque`, it works very well, i.e. 3 can be inserted successfully.

```
public MonotonicQueue() {
    monotonicQueue = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

I am wondering why one way works but the other can't. What happened here? Thank you!

Comment: I tried it out with `ArrayDeque` and it works! Why are you saying it does not work?

Comment: What does mean "it even fails to insert the first element"? In both cases the elements in the collection are stored properly. Could you provide what doesn't work?